# Increase div width size when collape sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<style type="text/css">
  .collapse {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.collapse.in.width {
  width: auto;
}
</style>
```

My horizontal collapse works fine however once collapsed I want the div class=span4 width to increase to the available viewport width space e.g: 8. and the button label to change to 'Show' and vice-versa using JQuery.

Comment: the width of which element? Can you post your js code too?

Comment: div class=span4 - The width of this div should increase once demo div is collapsed. I have no JS code only the above. Using bootstrap

Comment: Is this what you are looking to do? http://jsfiddle.net/jyekZ/

Comment: Jens NO the collapse is vertical as you will see from my code which works. But after my demo div is collapsed by clicking the button I want the first div to increase the width over the page. but when the button is clicked again it should go back as originally was.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch out the spanN class on the div when the collapse occurs using the event:

```
$('#demo').on('hidden', function () {
    $('#your-content-div').removeClass('span4').addClass('span8');
});
```

See the section on events under http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: thanks, But can you pls help me by animating the above as the div demo when collapsed. Also when the button is clicked again the divs should resize to their original sizes by animation. thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use transitions just as with the other one. Switching out the classes will still cause the transition to fire. For the opposite direction, you would just use 'show' instead of 'hidden' as the event you're watching for. Then you just remove 'span8' and add 'span4' (the reverse). You would use 'show' instead of 'shown', so that the content area will decrease in size *before* the sidebar actually comes back into view.

Comment: Chris will appreciate it if you can help me with some code / fiddle. if you have the time. thanks